# Good way to interact between different and same levels of depth (nested) in ReactJS ('States' + Hooks)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a **ReactJS** code (attached at the end of the post) where my objective is to find a good way to be able to "communicate" between some nested elements (I've tried to do a very simple code to explain my idea).

The columns are "hierarchy" based, so you have to active "A) Parent" before being able to active "A) Child 1".
The main objective is to be able to "disable" (basically, set the state 'active' into false) an element when:

- Some element of a "different column" is active
- Some element of the same column and "depth" is active

Some examples based on the code:

- Disable **'A) Parent'** when **'B) Parent'** is turned active.
- Disable **'A) Child 1'** when **'A) Child 2'** is turned active.
- Disable **'A) Child 1'** (and 'A) Parent') when **'B) Parent'** is turned active.

In this last example, we are also disabling the "ancestors" (since this "works" as a nested structure, where you have to turn on *A) Parent* to be able to turn on *A) Child X* ).

As you can see, the idea is to work on a depth level.. Where when you "enter" in another "path", the current active path should be disabled.

I've been trying some methods, but none of them have worked properly.
I think they are "expensive" and zero elegant.

My approaches have been something similar to this:

> - Give a "depth var" on each element.
> - Set a "current" var (useState) to App (root) and pass the "setCurrent" to each element.
> - Use a "useEffect" hook inside each looking for changes on current.
> - Then, conditionally try to manage them.

As I have said.. I'm pretty sure there are better methods to do this.. But I can't get with them.

Here is the code (for the example, I've tried to do the most simple setup without depth restriction, but remember that you have to "active" the ancestor before being able to "active" the descendant):
https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-rosalind-1oykv?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Have you tried looking into React's Context Api? It basically manages state on a global level and any child wrapped in that context will have access to those states and handlers  https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Shawn Yap has mentioned in the comments, finally I've opted for using Context Api.

Basically the idea is the following (very simplified):

1. Create a React Context:

   ```
   const MenuContext = React.createContext();
   ```
2. Declare it on you App and give it a initial value:

   ```
   const [context, setContext] = useState([0, 0, 0]);
   ```
3. Wrapp your menu structure with it:

   ```
   <MenuContext.Provider value={[context, setContext]}>
      <div className="App">
         {menu}
      </div>
   </MenuContext.Provider>
   ```
4. Give to your elements some way to identify them:

   ```
   <Element label="My Label" identifier={[1,0,0]} />
   ```
5. Inside your element, call your context with useContext:

   ```
   const [context, setContext] = useContext(MenuContext);
   ```
6. Finally, make some logic inside useEffect (using the context as a callback):

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
      if (active && props.identifier && context) { ... }
   }, [context]);
   ```

Depending on your needs, you will have to work with more or less complex logic, but the main idea of working with context is this.

Here is the codesand updated with an simple logic example: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-stallman-w38oe?file=/src/App.js